# What would prevent ESRI JSAPI AMD modules from being cached?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am using AMD style in the ESRI Javascript API (along with the esri application boilerplate: https://github.com/Esri/application-boilerplate-js).

For some reason, the AMD modules from the js.arcgis.com CDN do not appear to be cached and I've been unable to determine why.  Local AMD modules are caching fine:

[image: Example responses]

**Request headers:**

`Remote Address:54.230.50.98:80
Request URL:http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/js/esri/dijit/InfoView.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:rclg0=en; __unam=f220af1-14499213906-3dc5afe-11; esri_auth=[removed by author]
Host:js.arcgis.com
Referer: [removed by author]
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36`

I would suspect this is from the Cache-Control: max-age=0 header, but I have no idea what would be setting that and why.

Comment: The `Cache-Control:max-age=0` is being set by the server. That is what prevents the files from being cached. You cannot control that.

Comment: That's being sent in the request which would originate on the client, though.  It also doesn't make sense that esri would prevent caching of the modules.

Comment: Ok I misread your question. Your client's request header shouldn't send that header. Do you have any plugin or something else in your chrome that is attaching this to the request?

Answer (score -1):

*******Solution Below is Deprecated******

Use the HTML5 App Cache. To your HTML element add the manifest attribute like this

```
<html manifest="offline.appcache">
```

Then in the offline.appcache file list the resources you would like to cache. Updating the appcache file will force the browser to make the http request for the resource.

Fore more details see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

Comment: Just updating this here for anyone reading more recently. The App Cache mentioned in the previous post is Deprecated. 
“This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;“... “Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.”